# Count frequency when value in column A is lower than column B

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count occurrences that values in column A are lower than another column (column B)in Python.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create boolean mask by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) and use `sum`:

```
a = df.A.lt(df.B).sum()
```

Alternative:

```
a = (df.A < df.B).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do I need to use sum, if I want to count the frequency where the condition is met (i.e. when value in column A < column B)

Comment: @user12625679 - Can you add some sample data and expected output? Check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)